IntelliJ Idea 2024.2.1 missing the "New UI" option in Settings
Just updated IntelliJ and the UI reverted from classic to that clumsy New UI, without even asking me if I wanted it.
A startup tooltip indicated I could change it in the settings, yet the familiar "New UI" entry is missing under Settings > Appearance.
How do I go back to the old UI?

Checking the IntelliJ page about their new UI, there's a mention that the classic UI is now a plugin. And indeed Settings > Plugin > Marketplace provides a "Classic UI" plugin that reverts to the old UI. That is what the 2024.2.1 startup tip indicated. Also it changes the entire UI and still does not provide the old "Settings > Appareance > New UI" category from before.
IJ 2024.1 vs 2024.2.1 settings:

